# Need to store setting file on disk for Office Word 2007 Add-in (VSTO)

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

Im developing a simpel add-in for office and need a setting file, that is global for a machine.
What is the best place for it to be stored ?

I was think somewhere along the line of /User/all/appdata/...

Is there a standard way to store setting for a Office Add-in ?

Best place to store file, if no standard way is found ?

// dennis

Answer (score 0):

We have used the applicationsettings and it works well.

Application settings for all users
User settings for a specific user

**app.config**

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="CompanyName.Settings.ExcelAddInSettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="CompanyName.Settings.ExcelAddInSettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <CompanyName.Settings.ExcelAddInSettings>
            <setting name="AppValue1" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Value1</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="AppValue2" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Value2</value>
            </setting>
        </CompanyName.Settings.ExcelAddInSettings>
    </applicationSettings>
    <userSettings>
        <CompanyName.Settings.ExcelAddInSettings>
            <setting name="UserSetting1" serializeAs="String">
               <value>UserValue1</value>
            </setting>
        </CompanyName.Settings.ExcelAddInSettings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

If you haven't used the application setting before you can find details of them at [Application Settings Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx)

Comment: I also need to be enable to change the value of the key within the file. Since some value need to be changed, to set production or test environment. Where is the setting stored on disk ?

Comment: Application settings are stored in the folder where the VSTO dll is installed, they are not writable. User settings are placed in the users AppData folder, they are writable.  I would try to write the User settings via the settings mechanism (set the value and save) rather than editing the settings file directly.  If you need different configurations for different builds VS allows you to create different versions of the config files for different builds.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [.settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) file. You won't have to worry about where to store it -- the framework will take care of that for you. Just add a "Settings file" to your project.